# Using Stream to map Collection result

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to think of a way to do this without invoking `stream()` twice but to no avail:

```
List<Song> songs = service.getSongs();

List<ArtistWithSongs> artistWithSongsList = songs.stream()
    .collect(Collectors
        .groupingBy(s -> s.getArtist(), Collectors.toList()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(as -> new ArtistWithSongs(as.getKey(), as.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As requested:

```
class ArtistWithSongs {
    private Artist artist;
    private List<Song> songs;

    ArtistWithSongs(Artist artist, List<Song> songs) {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.songs = songs;
    }
}
```

Is there a more optimal way of doing this?

Comment: Can you post your `ArtistWithSongs` class?

Comment: I doubt it is possible to group the elements of a stream without collecting them.

Comment: No getters or setters? Is it supposed to be immutable?

Comment: Currently yes, but if you think it can be done with mutable version feel free to try.

Comment: This is already optimal. There are solutions without streaming twice possible, but they are less clean, more complicated and not offering significant performance gains. Well, you can simplify the `groupingBy` by omitting the `toList()` collector: `.groupingBy(s -> s.getArtist())` or `.groupingBy(Song::getArtist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use FlatMap:

```
List<Song> songs = service.getSongs();

List<ArtistWithSongs> artistWithSongsList = songs.stream()
               .collect(Collectors
               .groupingBy(s -> s.getArtist(), Collectors.toList()))
               .entrySet()
               .flatMap(as -> new ArtistWithSongs(as.getKey(), as.getValue()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Edit:

Sorry we cannot use flatMap after collect() because it doesnot return stream. Other solution is:

```
    List<ArtistWithSongs> artistWithSongsList = new ArrayList<>();
    songs.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Song::getArtist))
         .forEach((artist, songs) -> artistWithSongsList.add(new ArtistWithSongs(artist, songs)););
```

Comment: You can't call `flatMap` on a `Set`, did you omit a `.stream()` somewhere?

Comment: You save my life. :D

Answer (score 2):

I think by using forEach is enough in this case :

```
List<ArtistWithSongs> artistWithSongsList = new ArrayList<>();
service.getSongs().stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getArtist(), Collectors.toList()))
                  .entrySet()
                  .forEach((k, v) -> artistWithSongsList.add(new ArtistWithSongs(k, v)););
```